# Gitlab job failed with exit code2 after execution of owasp zap scanner

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, owasp, exit-code, zap

Gitlab job are failing with exit code 2 after execution. No error details are appearing in log file only showing ERROR: Job failed: exit code 2.

**.gitlab.ci.yml file:**

```
image: docker:latest

services:
- name: docker:dind
  alias: thedockerhost

variables:
   DOCKER_HOST: tcp://thedockerhost:2375/
   DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
   DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

stages:
  - test1

test1:
  stage: test1
  script:
    - docker run -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw --name zap2 owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py -t http://www.example.com -r example.html
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths: 
      - example.html
```

Comment: Launching the command manually on my home machine returns rc=2 as well. I guess it is because there are warnings (e.g. `WARN-NEW: Missing Anti-clickjacking Header [10020] x 1` to name only one). What is the actual problem with that? Just manage that return code as a success in your script.

Comment: In case you don't know where to look: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failureexit_codes

Answer (score -1):

The the documentation:

- https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/full-scan/
- https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/baseline-scan/
- https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/api-scan/

`-I                do not return failure on warning`

If you want to understand the various exit states you can check the Open Source code: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/tree/main/docker

For further information about using ZAP's packaged scans and docker images refer to: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/